# How to get function to fire when buttonless form is submitted

Tags: javascript

I have a page with many forms on it. could be 1..200. None of these forms have buttons and they are built programatically. I am using jquery to submit all the forms that are checked.

```
   function FakeName()
   {

           $("input:checked").parent("form").submit();

   }
```

My forms look like:

```
            <form name="FakeForm<%=i%>" action="javascript:void%200" onSubmit="processRow(<%=i%>)" method="post" style="margin:0px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="FakeNameCheck" value="FakeNameCheck"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="FakeNum" value="<%= FakeNum%>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="FakeId" value="<%=FakeIdr%>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="FakeAmt" value="<%=FakeAmount%>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="FakeTrans" value="FakeTrans"/>
            </form>
```

Note: action is set to "javascript:void%200" so that it posts to a fake page. I want to handle my own posting in processRow.

OnSubmit never gets called and therefore ProcessRow never gets called.

Obviously all the names of the functions and variables have been changed to protect their identity :D

How can I get a function in each form to fire when I call submit programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onsubmit` handler is deliberately not triggered when you programatically submit the form. This is to avoid infinite recursion if an event handler would cause the event to be triggered again (and therefore the event handler to be called again)

However, of course you can call the `processRow()` function yourself in place of the `.submit()` call.

You're allowed to have inputs outside of forms. One school of thought is that a `<form>` shouldn't be a `<form>` if it's not intended to be submitted to the server via HTML.

Comment: yeah. Was thinking it would be easier to group all my needed fields into a form so then I could iterate through all the forms. Would suggest using a div for this instead? I will have many FakeForms on the page.

Comment: To be honest, a better solution would be to leave the forms as they are but use an action="..." which can process the result if the form is submitted (by a user without javascript, for example).

However graceful non-javascript degradation is a whole other ball game than your question is based on

Answer (score 0):

Look up [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=En/DOM/Element.dispatchEvent) and it's equivalent [fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423(VS.85).aspx). It's not the easiest thing in the world to use, but I think that's what you are looking for.

I'm surprised that there's no library that helps with this easily. Prototype (the one I've used the most) comes closest with a .fire() method on elements.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I may be able to do this:

```
<form name="FakeForm<%=i%>" action="javascript:processRow(<%=i%>)" method="post" style="margin:0px;">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="FakeNameCheck" value="FakeNameCheck"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="FakeNum" value="<%= FakeNum%>"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="FakeId" value="<%=FakeIdr%>"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="FakeAmt" value="<%=FakeAmount%>"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="FakeTrans" value="FakeTrans"/>
                        </form>
```

Are there any drawbacks to this?